# Не могли бы Вы помочь осознать, в чем у меня ошибка в коде на языке Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Не могли бы Вы помочь осознать, в чем у меня ошибка в коде?
Очень нужно разобраться..

***Задача:***
Описать на Прологе базу знаний, содержащую следующую информацию:
**Факты:**

1. Алексей – сын Юрия,
2. Юрий – сын Ивана,
3. Сергей – сын Ивана,
4. Александр – сын Ивана,
5. Павел – сын Сергея.

**Правила:**

1. X является отцом Y, если Y – сын X
2. X является братом Y, если это два разных человека, но оба являются сыновьями одного и того же человека
3. X является дядей Y, если отцом Y является Z, а X и Z – братья
4. X является дедушкой Y, если X – отец Z, а Z – отец Y

**Сформулировать цели и ответить на следующие вопросы:**

1. Вывести список братьев Сергея
2. Как зовут дедушку Павла?
3. Кем приходится Сергей Алексею?

```
predicates
  nondeterm son(string,string) /*who, whose*/
  nondeterm father(string,string) /*who, whose*/
  nondeterm brother(string,string) /*who, whose*/
  nondeterm uncle(string,string) /*(who, whose*/
  nondeterm grandfather(string,string) /*who, whose*/
clauses
%Facts
  son(aleksej,yurij). 
  son(yurij,ivan). 
  son(sergej,ivan). 
  son(alexandr,ivan). 
  son(pavel,sergej). 
%Rules
  father(X,Y):-son(Y,X).
  brother(X,Y):-X<>Y,father(Z,X),father(Z,Y).
  uncle(X,Y):-father(Z,Y), brother(X,Z),brother(Z,X).
  grandfather(X,Y):-father(X,Z),father(Z,Y).
goal
  brother(X,sergej).
  grandfather(X,pavel).
  X(sergej,aleksej).
```

Вроде бы всё логично, должно скомпилироваться и выдать результат, но почему-то выдает ошибки..
Не понимаю, что не так..

Comment: как минимум нужно добавить в вопрос ошибки, которые ты получаешь

Comment: _X(sergej,aleksej)_ - у тебя нет предиката X

Comment: и еще непонятная конструкция: `brother(X,Z),brother(Z,X)` - у тебя же без разницы в каком порядке аргументы передавать

Comment: Ошибка: E;Test_Goal, pos: 589, 450 Syntax error, section keyword expected

Comment: Это на какую строку из приведенного кода ругается?

Comment: Можете подсказать, как следует исправить код, чтобы он заработал, скомпилировался?

Comment: да вот сама не понимаю на какую он ругается, учитывая, что у меня не так много строк .. Эта ошибка появляется в Visual Prolog v.5.2 Personal Edition for Windows 32

Comment: Если попробовать вбить этот код на сайты онлайн-компиляторов для языка Пролог, то тогда будет указывать на конкретные строки.. В эти онлайн-компиляторы вбивала код: http://swish.swi-prolog.org/  , http://ideone.com/70keHI

Comment: @Gadget откуда взят этот код?

Comment: откуда? написан мной

Comment: Как минимум цель(goal) должна быть одна. А у тебя три написано. Кроме этого в разных версиях компиляторов разные операторы сравнения. Ну и про то, что нет предиката `X` я уже говорил

Comment: а как можно переписать тогда третью цель (кем приходится Сергей Алексею)? Если так нельзя это выяснить :"X(sergej,aleksej)"?

Comment: Переписала так цель :"brother(X,sergej), write(X), nl, grandfather(Y,pavel), write(Y), nl" Теперь могу получить ответ для первых двух вопросов, но не знаю, как вывести ответ для третьего вопроса (кем приходится Сергей Алексею)..

Comment: Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу стоит заметить, что здесь решать задачи за вас не будут.
Теперь по сути.
Очевидно, что у вас нет предиката X(Y,Z), который бы приводил в соответствие каждой ситуации родства слово кем является Y для Z.

Пример такого предиката:

```
    Who(Y,Z,X):-brother(Y,Z), X="brother",
    Who(Y,Z,X):-father(Y,Z), X="father",
    ...
```

И так описать все возможные ситуации для этого предиката, не забыть и про племянников и внуков. Разумеется, код может быть не рабочим, так как для Prolog уйма различных вариаций интерпретаторов языка.

Но идея общая дана.

P.S. В том интерпретаторе с которым работал я должен был быть только один goal, не уверен насчёт вашего.

Comment: я понимаю, что никто не будет.

Comment: Всё поняла, в чем ошибка,получилось, спасибо.